# Item Level and their average armor/dps in Diablo 3

Tags: diablo-iii

Is there any handy reference as to what is the range of DPS and armor for items of a particular level? A lot of time I would get, say a crossbow that does 300 DPS for item level 55, but I have no idea how good that is whe

Comment: Looks like you were about to say "when" and add another sentence

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the [items section of Battle.net](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/). There you see the different weapons and armor pieces.

But since you probably won't use white items it's hard to say how good an item is, because they are rolled randomly (except you have good "game experience" and know what is good and what's not).

So if you want to know how good an item is you would need to take a look in the Auction House and look at items of an appropriate level (and/or rarity).

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, the easiest way is to check in the AH and keep your own list. This should not be that hard, as you only need to look from level 50 upwards, as only these drop in Inferno.

My personal experience is the following DPS values are considered "good" at the moment for 2h weapons:

- level 50: 300-400
- level 54: 400-600
- level 57: 600+

The values are slightly less for 1h weapons.

Furthermore very few people would actually invest a huge amount of gold for a level 40 weapon and below. The weapon value decreases with each level and up to say level 40 you level way too fast.

Answer (score 0):

I find the auction house is a great way to find out the average of weapons DPS for a heroes level...set the level max in search:)